# how to connect two Windows computers by USB for communication between their virtual serial ports?

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, com

What is needed for the physical USB connection between two Windows computers for communication between their virtual serial ports? 
Should I use USB/serial adapters?

I am building a .NET terminal app on Windows 10 Pro computer that must use a virtual serial port for communication through a USB connection to the virtual serial COM port at a Windows 7 Pro computer that is running the terminal app on .NET.

The terminal app is the PortChat example app from [MSDN's serial port documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2).

PURPOSE:  I need to test a serial communication .NET app on Windows 10 that will eventually communicate with an embedded STM that is presently unavailable .

Comment: Like what?  What other site deals with networking two, Windows computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with two USB serial adapters and a null-modem cable.  If you just need something quick that is known to work, this is a good option (I suggest either FTID or PL2303 based adapters for this, they seem to be more reliable when talking to other USB-to-Serial adapters in my experience than other options).

However, you may be able to find a cable that just does the whole thing for you.  I already know such things exist for Ethernet connections (those 'USB transfer' cables you see advertised sometimes are cases of this, they have two USB-to_ethernet adapters hard-wired to each other), so I would actually be a bit surprised if such hardware did not exist already.